# Tkinter object sensitivity to mouse-pointer

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse

I am making a program with python using tkinter, but I have a problem. I need to add a code which makes my tkinter object sense when the mouse-pointer is touching it.

Does anyone have recommendations for what I should do? So far, I've been thinking that I could write code which runs like this: If the coordinates of the mouse-pointer are the same as the coordinates of the object, the object would react to that instead.

Comment: What do you want it to do when it hovers overtop of it?

Comment: You can do it by binding event handler functions to the `'<Enter>'` and `'<Leave>'` mouse events. Here's some [example code](https://jakirkpatrick.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/making-a-hovering-box-in-tkinter/). It's sometimes called "hover" or "hovering".

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events. They will fire whenever the mouse pointer enters and leaves a widget.

Here's a small demo:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_mouse_enter(event):
    print("enter...", event.widget)

def on_mouse_leave(event):
    print("leave...", event.widget)

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(10):
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Item #{}".format(i), name='label-{}'.format(i))
    label.pack()
    label.bind("<Enter>", on_mouse_enter)
    label.bind("<Leave>", on_mouse_leave)

tk.mainloop()
```